# Azure Service Fabric and API Management Integration

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-api-management

I have provisioned a service fabric cluster on azure. It has two node types: one for the frontend and the other one for the backend.

I have deployed a Stateless self-hosted API on the frontend node-type. Now what i'd like to do is to expose that service through the Azure API Management. I've been trying to import the API without success. I have also tried to use swagger to generate the service specification but it seems that swagger does not work. I can access the swagger URL but it loads a blank page.

Any suggestions on how I can integrate my stateless service with APIM or how swagger works here?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are a few different ways you can produce your swagger document. If you are using Web API, you can use [SwashBuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) to generate your Swagger for you. To validate your swagger file, you can use [Swagger Editor](http://swagger.io/swagger-editor/). Finally, if you still have problems once you have validated your swagger document, share the document and the error here and we will see what we can do to assist.

Many thanks